# Second order differential equation with variation of parameters wrong exponent?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I'm trying to refresh my memory on the subject.
Suppose we have

$$
x'' + 2\alpha x' + \omega^2 x = f
$$

where $0 < \alpha < \omega$, we know in this situation two L.I. solutions are
$$
x_1(t) = e^{-\alpha t} \sin(\omega t), x_2(t) = e^{-\alpha t} \cos(\omega t)
$$

By variation of parameters my particular solution is given by
$$
x_p = x_1 g_1 + x_2 g_2
$$

with the property

$$
x_1 g'_1 + x_2 g'_2 = 0
$$

Using such condition leads me to

$$
g_1(t) = \int_{t_0}^t \frac{\left|\begin{matrix} f(t) & x_2'(t) \\ 0 & x_2(t)\end{matrix}\right|}{\left|\begin{matrix} x_1'(t) & x_2'(t) \\ x_1(t) & x_2(t)\end{matrix}\right|} dt
$$

and
$$
g_2(t) = \int_{t_0}^t \frac{\left|\begin{matrix} x_1'(t) & f(t) \\ x_1(t) & 0\end{matrix}\right|}{\left|\begin{matrix} x_1'(t) & x_2'(t) \\ x_1(t) & x_2(t)\end{matrix}\right|} dt
$$

Now here's where I get confused, I'll only consider $g_1(t)$, in this case

$$\left|\begin{matrix} x_1'(t) & x_2'(t) \\ x_1(t) & x_2(t)\end{matrix}\right| = -\omega e^{-2\alpha t}$$

while

$$
\left|\begin{matrix} f(t) & x_2'(t) \\ 0 & x_2(t)\end{matrix}\right| = e^{-\alpha t} sin(\omega t) f(t)
$$

This leads me to the integral

$$
g_(t) = -\frac{1}{\omega} \int_{t_0}^t e^{\alpha t} \sin(\omega t) f(t) dt
$$

Is everything I've done correct so far? The factor $e^{\alpha t}$ in the integrand I am not sure is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for these basis solutions your equation would have to be formulated as
$$
x''+2αx'+(α^2+ω^2)x=f.
$$
Or you would have to use the frequency $\sqrt{ω^2-α^2}$ in the basis solutions, as long as this is a real number.

Comment: My bad, I didn't solve the homogenous correctly.